# Select a range of key/value pairs in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, local-storage

Here is a post as a Self Learner.

My task:

I have a dictionary with 15.000 entries. The user can select whether the entries are being displayed or not by checking a checkbox related to each dictionary entry.

The checkboxes and entries are displayed in dynamically generated lists, the user choses the length of the lists.

The state of the checkboxes is stored in localStorage with either of the two:

```
localStorage(key,true);
localStorage(key,null);
```

and the checkboxes are set to :checked if their related key is paired to "true".

Now I need an update button to reset an entire list to "all checkboxes not selected".

This seemed a difficult task to me, as the length of the list is dynamically set, and, I also feared that my function would affect the entire localStorage.

Comment: In what situation or event do you have to read/persists user selections? It doesn't make sense that you write to the local storage for every change in any checkbox selection.

Comment: I am not writing the change in the checkbox selection to localStorage, but the change occuring inside an svg graphic. Once the user is done interacting in the svg, the checkboxlist should reflect those interactions. An  _updateStorage button_ just resets the checkbox list to _all checked_,  which affects the svg graphic to _all shown_ .I will ponder your suggestion to write to localStorage only once, in this case at the end of the interaction with the svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would **structure the data** (not strictly):

```
var checkboxes = {
    "key-1": {    // might as well do to say: "key-1": true/false
        "checked": true
    },
    "key-2": {
        "checked": false
    },
    ...,
    "key-n-1": {
        "checked": true/false
    },
    "key-n": {
        "checked": true/false
    }
};
```

Here's how I would **define the update function**:

```
function updateStorage(){
    var serialisedData = JSON.stringify(checkboxes);
    localStorage.setItem("checkboxes-state", serialisedData);
};
```

Here's how I would **read the stored data**:

```
function readStorage(){
    var serialisedData = localStorage.getItem("checkboxes-state");
    // then deserialise it
    var data = JSON.parse(serialisedData);
    // it may be empty
    if(!data){
        checkboxes = {}; // if empty initialise it
    } else {
        checkboxes = data;
    }
}
```

Here's how I would **update the state of appropriate elements in the DOM with the data that was read**, and **update the data when checkboxes state change**:

```
d3.selectAll(".box").each(function(){
    if(checkboxes.hasOwnProperty(this.id)){
        this.checked = checkboxes[this.id].checked;
    }
}).on("change", function(){
    if(checkboxes.hasOwnProperty(this.id)){
        checkboxes[this.id].checked = this.checked;
    }else{
        checkboxes[this.id] = {
            "checked": this.checked
        };
    }
});
```

It doesn't make sense to read/write the storage frequently. Ideally and for most normal use cases, one read per session will suffice. And a minimum of one save will be required.

You may refine your question and I can give you a more specific answer.

---

### Putting it all together

```
var checkboxes = {
    "key-1": {    // might as well do to say: "key-1": true/false
        "checked": true
    },
    "key-2": {
        "checked": false
    },
    ...,
    "key-n-1": {
        "checked": true/false
    },
    "key-n": {
        "checked": true/false
    }
};

var updateStorage = function(){
    var serialisedData = JSON.stringify(checkboxes);
    localStorage.setItem("checkboxes-state", serialisedData);
};

var readStorage = function(){
    var serialisedData = localStorage.getItem("checkboxes-state");
    // then deserialise it
    var data = JSON.parse(serialisedData);
    // it may be empty
    if(!data){
        checkboxes = {}; // if empty (i.e. if this was the first time the application was run on the current client) initialise it
    } else {
        checkboxes = data; // if we have data, restore it by assigning it to `checkboxes` variable
    }

    // having read the checkboxes states from the local storage, we reflect the read data on the DOM
    d3.selectAll(".box").each(function(){
        if(checkboxes.hasOwnProperty(this.id)){
            this.checked = checkboxes[this.id].checked;
        }
    });
};

// on application load, read the storage
readStorage();

// bind the update function to its trigger button
d3.select("#update").on("click", updateStorage);

// update the `checkboxes` variable whenever user makes changes in selections
d3.selectAll(".box").on("change", function(){
    if(checkboxes.hasOwnProperty(this.id)){
        // update existing entry
        checkboxes[this.id].checked = this.checked;
    }else{
        // add new entry and set its state
        checkboxes[this.id] = {
            "checked": this.checked
        };
    }
});
```

So there you go.

Comment: Thank you. How would you update serializedData.    The user goes through an extensive list to make preselections out of a dictionary.    The checked items are displayed in an svg display. Inside this display the user can interact and select the items again, chosing if he wants them to remain being displayed or, having been learned, be removed from the display section. This latter action also resets the here described checkboxes to true or null, thus changes localStorage. On reload, the list as well as the content of the svg is gotten from localStorage, and those are identical.

Comment: Add on: the id of the checkboxes contains the vaue of the dictionary entries. That allows a simple filter solution in the svg display. Example: 100 words are displazed in the svg. You decide 50 of them are to easy, then you can select them in the svg on the fly or in the checkbox list to not be displayed anymore.

Comment: In answer to your question > "How would you update serializedData"? - It is updated by first deserialising it, thus getting back the original data. Then you can update the data object as usual, when you're done using the data object, you once again serialise and save to local storage. The statement `var data = JSON.parse(serialisedData);` as in the answer above, achieves the deserialisation. The value `data` will be identical to the last saved `checkboxes`, based on a comparison of their properties and content.

Comment: I updated my answer, not tested, does it seem conceptually correct ? Still working through your example. Not sure I would need to stringify that way?

Comment: Ok,  parse makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Based, on your earlier comments, the sample I gave appears quite fitting. Now looking at the answer you have updated, I wonder why you have reverted to using an array for storing checkbox states. An hash map as before is more reasonable.

Comment: I see. I was trying to write to localStorage once onz, thought an array would allow that best. Your answer is fitting very well, thank you.

Comment: I suggest you inspect everything on the browser console, everything will then make more sense to you.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. It makes sense now. I had to look up hasOwnProperty first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83640/discussion-between-ed-die-and-igwe-kalu).

Answer (score 0):

Modified. Intent is to reset multiple checked checkboxes to unchecked and have the changes persist in localStorage:

```
d3.select("#update").on("click",storeNull);

function storeNull () {


      var updatethis = d3.selectAll(".box").filter(":checked").each(function(){

      var use_it = this.id;
      localStorage.setItem(use_it,null);

      });

};
```